# Should I post a relatively generic answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I often find myself knowing how to approach a problem that someone has posed but I can't offer an answer that gives *specific* advice on exactly which function to call due to lack of API knowlege of, say, .NET, or the particular library they are using.

What do people feel about posting a generic answer? Should I bother?

Here's my current thinking:

From a general point of view, are such answers just noise? Especially when the question is answered by someone with a more specific knowledge, providing an API ref, method name or code.

From my point of view I have been downvoted in comparison when a more specific answer arrives. Whilst I endeavour not to take it personally, it can be a little disheartening.

The main justification - that I can think of - for providing a generic answer is that it gives someone a few ideas to go away with so that they can perhaps get a new angle on their problem.

I guess in some ways I'm also attempting to second guess the kind of answer that someone is after. So perhaps it would be more beneficial to post a comment instead.

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view as someone who asks questions, I am always grateful for some pointers. Adding a generic answer AFTER a specialized one (for the same thing) was added is bad.

When I ask a question, I'd rather have a rough answer ASAP and then I'll leave it some time for "better" answers to come in. But then again, I usually try not to ask "Plz send me the codes" question, so normally a vague answer is already good enough to get me going in the right direction.

However, if you are really just "guessing", maybe a comment works better - always depends on the exact situation.